# How can I trace the files and functions a particular terminal uses?

Tags: python, openstack

In Openstack, lets say for example, i'm entering the command and i start up an instance using the image myimage and use flavor 1.

```
nova boot --image myimage --flavor 1 server1
```

How can i actually trace this command and get details like what functions are executed, which files it enters while executing the command etc.,

Sorry I'm a linux noob and i'm trying to find ways to trace few calls. Instead of doing this by going through all the files and doing this.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[STRACE](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/strace.1.html)

> strace - trace system calls and signals
>
> In the simplest case strace runs the specified  command  until  it 
>   exits.   It  intercepts  and records  the  system calls which are
>   called by a process and the signals which are received by a process. 
>   The name of each system call, its arguments and its return value are
>   printed on  standard error or to the file specified with the -o
>   option.

```
strace <command>
```

You can filter what you would like to trace using the `-e trace=` option. For example, `strace -e trace=file <command>` "trace all system calls which take a file name as an argument". Read the man page for more options.